# How to merge multiple binary files into parquet in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have several binary files that I need to merge into one parquet files in spark. I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles("/mypath/*").map{case (filePath, content) =>
      Row("file_name" -> filePath, "content" -> content.toArray())
    }
val schema = new StructType().add(StructField("file_name", StringType, true)).add(StructField("content", ArrayType(ByteType), true))
spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema).show(1)
```

I got this stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.Tuple2 is not a valid external type for schema of string
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, file_name), StringType), true) AS file_name#55
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, file_name), StringType), true)
   :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt
   :  :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
   :  :  +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
   :  +- 0
   :- null
   +- staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, file_name), StringType), true)
      +- validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, file_name), StringType)
         +- getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, file_name)
            +- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
               +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.Tuple2 is not a valid external type for schema of string
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply_0$(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:276)
  ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error says, you declared the column to be a `StringType` but the actual data is a tuple

```
Row("file_name" -> filePath, "content" -> content.toArray())
```

Here you create a row of two tuples but your schema is a string column and an array column. Your assumption that you need to create a tuple with the column name is incorrect, you just use the data. Column names come when you apply a schema.

use `Row(filePath, content.toArray())` instead to match your schema, or alter your schema to accept the tuples.